# Is this translation of "Stop blaming yourself but just remember it for long" correct?

Tags: traducción, redacción

These days, I have to translate some sentences of a TV Korean program to Spanish.

The meaning of the sentence that I have to translate is:

> Stop blaming yourself but just remember it for long.

If I translate to Spanish, would it be ok to say:

> Deja de culparte a ti mismo, pero recuérdalo por mucho tiempo.

?

I hope you correct my sentence.

Comment: I think that the translation is accurate.

Comment: The problem is that the ***English sentence does not make sense in English***. What does "just remember it for long" mean? That is not idiomatic as written with the first part of the sentence. Thus, before translating it, it's best to fix the English. What does the **it** refer to?

Comment: I agree with @Lambie You should add some context so we better understand what "it" is. Even in Spanish it doesn't make a lot of sense "recuérdalo por mucho tiempo" has no relation to "deja de culparte".

Comment: As the other comments imply, it's [generally ungrammatical](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153592/for-long-vs-for-a-long-time) to end a positive declarative sentence in English with "for long". You might be better phrasing it as `"Stop blaming yourself, just remember it for a long time."`

Comment: Surely the "it" is whatever the person being addressed is blaming him/herself for? The sentence is very awkward in English but seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's mostly correct. However, in Spain's Spanish "por mucho tiempo" is not very frequent, although it probably is in Spanish speaking countries in America. In Spain, we'd most likely say "recuérdalo mucho tiempo," "recuérdalo siempre" or, even, "recuérdalo para siempre." Admittedly, the last two versions change the meaning a bit.

Comment: Bienvenido Patricio. Te sugeriría que edites la respuesta y adiciones si consideras que la traducción es correcta o como lo cambiarías. Así como está es solo un comentario sobre una parte de la pregunta. Esperamos seguir viendo tus contribuciones.